# Undefined result in console

Tags: javascript, node.js, steambot

I am getting "deposited over undefined" result for current_game with this synthax when running node.js:

```
if(offer.items_to_receive == undefined) return;             
mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE `name`=\'maxitems\'', 
function(err, row, fields) {

    if(offer.items_to_receive.length > row[0].value) {
        offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid});
        offer.items_to_receive = [];
        var unixtime = Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000.0);
        mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO `messages` (`userid`,`msg`,`from`, `win`, `system`, `time`) VALUES (\''+offer.steamid_other+'\',\'Sorry, but you deposited too many items\',\'System\', \'0\', \'1\', \''+unixtime+'\')', function(err, row, fields) {});
        return;
    } else {
        mysqlConnection.query('SELECT `value` FROM `info` WHERE         `name`=\'current_game\'', 
        function(err, row, fields) {  
            var current_game = (row[0].value);
            mysqlConnection.query('SELECT COUNT(item) FROM `game' + current_game + '` AS maxitemperperson WHERE `userid`=\''+offer.steamid_other+'\'' , function(err, row) {  
                someVari = row[0].maxitemperperson;
                console.log('Deposited over ' +someVari);
                if((someVari + offer.items_to_receive.length) > 10) {
                    offers.declineOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid});                        
                    mysqlConnection.query('INSERT INTO `messages` (`userid`,`msg`,`from`, `win`, `system`, `time`) VALUES (\''+offer.steamid_other+'\',\'Sorry, but you deposited too many items\',\'System\', \'0\', \'1\', \''+unixtime+'\')', function(err, rowl, fields) {});
                    return;
                }
            })
        })
    }
});
```

Where is the error in the synthax? Basically, the first part till "else" is working, but afterwards I am trying to count the number of items from a certain table (which is generated dynamically through the current_game variable) that have the same userid and afterwards add another number of items and compare with 10 (which can also be written as row[0].value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check what `console.log(row)` contains

Comment: I just said that. It says "Deposited over undefined." so maxitemperperson is undefined. Why?

Comment: I did console.dir(someVari); and it's undefined .. is the sql statement wrong? I think the sql statement has a problem getting the value

Comment: Also https://gyazo.com/200dad6406005178c4a63609f3a2bd3e so there's no problem with getting the current_game. (did console.dir(current_game))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `AS` alias in the wrong place in the SQL statement:

```
'SELECT COUNT(item) FROM `game' + current_game + '` AS maxitemperperson WHERE `userid`=\''+offer.steamid_other+'\''
```

This will alias the table name, so you could do `COUNT(maxitemperperson.item)` to reference it (useful if you have more than one table in the query).

What you want is this:

```
'SELECT COUNT(item) AS maxitemperperson FROM `game' + current_game + '` WHERE `userid`=\''+offer.steamid_other+'\''
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! :) And the bot responded properly to the script:)

Answer (score 1):

`someVari = row[0].maxitemperperson;` is assigning `undefined` to `someVari`.

That means that `row[0]` exists but does not have a property named `maxitemperperson` (or, less likely, that the property exists but itself is set to `undefined`).

As a minimal debugging technique, you can use `console.dir(row[0]);` to find out what's going on.

You should also check that the query did not result in an error by examining the value of `err` in your callback.

Comment: I did console.dir(someVari); and it's undefined .. is the sql statement wrong?

Comment: I wouldn't say wrong, rather incomplete. You only request `COUNT(item)` in your SQL statement, so the result only contains this. Change it to `SELECT COUNT(item),maxitemperperson ...` and it should work (assuming this column exists in the database).

Comment: I want to attribute the variable the count(item) result. Maxitemperperson does not exist. It's just an alias for the result of the select statement.

Comment: Then `SELECT COUNT(item) AS maxitemperperson` should do it.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider so what's the problem then..?